# How can I populate a table view, not a table view controller?

Tags: xcode, swift, view, tableview, viewcontroller

I have a table view inside a normal view controller and I was wondering how I should go out populating it with data?

After researching it, everywhere I have seen it done uses a table view controller: I am just using a view controller with a table view inside it.

How should I populate this with data? I have created an IBOutlet in my `ViewController.swift`, but I'm not sure what to do to add data.

The reason I am not using a table view controller is because I couldn't get the navigation bar to show up and I heard that the navigation bar scrolled.

Is it possible to use a table view inside a normal view controller? Should I be using  table view controller? If it is possible to use a table view inside a normal view controller, how do I populate the table view?

The coding language I am using is swift.

Answer (score 1):

A `UITableViewController` is basically a normal `UIViewController` which has its main view replaced with a `UITableView` and uses the `UITableviewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

`UITableViewController` is subclass of `UIViewController`.

So just add the protocols and use it exactly the way you use it in `UITableViewController`.